# putting label value into a databounded gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<div align ="right">
       <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="42px" ImageUrl="~/back.png" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" />
       <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="45px" ImageUrl="~/gnome-logout-icone-3872-128.png" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
   </div>
<div align="center">
<asp:Label ID="lb1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 <h1><font color="olive">User Details</font></h1>
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 369px;"  cellspacing="1">
<tr>
  <td width="77" height="16" align="left" ><b><font size="2" color="red">Name:</font></b></td>
  <td width="77" height="16" align="left" ><b><font size="2">&nbsp;<asp:Label
          ID="UserName" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br /></font></b></td>

  <td width="77" height="16" align="left" ><b><font size="2" color="red">StaffCode:</font></b></td>
  <td width="77" height="16" align="left" ><b><font size="2">&nbsp;<asp:Label
          ID="lbl_address" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br /></font></b></td>

  <td width="77" height="16" align="left" ><b><font size="2" color="red">Branch:</font></b></td>
  <td width="77" height="16" align="left" ><b><font size="2">&nbsp;<asp:Label
          ID="lbl_sal" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br /></font></b></td>

  <td width="77" height="16" align="left" ><b><font size="2" color="red">Designation:</font></b></td>
  <td width="77" height="16" align="left" ><b><font size="2">&nbsp;<asp:Label
          ID="lbl_phone" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label><br /></font></b></td> 
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

No Of Records :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Branch">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBranch" runat="server" Height="18px" Width="72px"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" Text="<%# System.DateTime.Now.ToString() %>" runat="server" Height="18px" Width="72px"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SrNo">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

//Now what I am unable to do is I want to put a lable value into textbox of //gridview The label(lbl_sal)shows me the Branch I want to put its value into //textbox(TextBox ID="BranchName"  ). Is there any way

Comment: There is no TextBox `BranchName`

Comment: Is your GridView show correctly with textBox ? Is there any `Datasource` for it ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter , I think it's `txtBranch` :)

Answer (score 0):

A `GridView` typically contains multiple rows, that's the sole reason for this control. For that reason it's confusing if you want to assign a single value to a `TextBox` in the grid.

Normally you control the input through the `DataSource` of the `GridView`. So if you modifies that you will get that value into the grid.

If you want to assign that value to every row in the grid without modifying the datasource you could use `RowDataBound`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox txtBranch (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtBranch"); 
        txtBranch.Text = lbl_sal.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to fill all the rows of textBranch with the value of the label ,I used this source but the problem is it is not accepting(e.Row.RowType). Can you tell me why is the problem @Tim Schmelter

Comment: What exception do you get and on which line exactly?

Comment: Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1528: Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration)